# RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log and invalid value encountered in true_divide

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying to run some code that I found on GitHub (let me know if I need to reference code that you obtain from other sources on Stack OverFlow please) but I am having an issue with an error that says

> "RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log and invalid value encountered in true_divide"

How can you resolve this when pixel values are being read into your matrix that may include zeros? Additionally, I have attached the image I was utilizing.

[image]

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os


def rgb2ii(img, alpha):
    """Convert RGB image to illumination invariant image."""
    ii_image = (0.5 + np.log(img[:, :, 1] / float(255)) -
                alpha * np.log(img[:, :, 2] / float(255)) -
                (1 - alpha) * np.log(img[:, :, 0] / float(255)))

    return ii_image


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    image = os.path.join("/Python/OpenCv/Images/MFB1.png")
    source_img = cv2.imread(image, 1)

    a = 0.333  # Camera alpha
    invariant_img = rgb2ii(source_img, a)
    invariant_img /= np.amax(invariant_img) # invariant_img = invariant_img / np.amax(invariant_img)

    cv2.imshow("RGB Image", source_img)
    cv2.imshow("Illumination Invariant", invariant_img)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embrace the NaN.

Numpy has functions to detect NaNs and infinities, which are `np.isnan` and `np.isinf`. You can use the mask resulting from those to select and erase NaN/infinity values after they happen.

```py
calculation = np.log([-1, 0, 1]) # -> [nan, -inf, 0]
infmask = np.isinf(calculation)
nanmask = np.isnan(calculation)
calculation[infmask] = 9999
calculation[nanmask] = 12345
```

Or change the math so it *doesn't* happen in the first place. The typical trick is to add a small "epsilon", in your case to the argument of the logarithm, that makes it positive/non-zero in all cases (assuming it was >= 0 before) and otherwise is small enough compared to "regular" values as to not affect the result too much... causing `log(0+epsilon)` to become *merely near* infinite instead of an *actual* infinity.